# Owin auth - how to get IP address of client requesting the auth token

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, owin

Using Owin Security, I'm trying to make the API have 2 methods of authentications.

Is there a property in the `context` variable (`OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext`) that lets me access the **IP address** of the **client** sending the initial request for an auth token to the API?

A basic strip of my auth method looks like so:

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(
    OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var remoteIpAddresss = context.Request.RemoteIpAddress;
        var localIpAddress = context.Request.LocalIpAddress;


        // ... authenticate process goes here (AddClaim, etc.)
    }
}
```

From what I understand the `remoteIpAddress` and `localIpAddress` are the API's (i.e. where the API is hosted). How do I know from what IP address (and port) the request was sent from?

Would the client need to send this information themselves?

Should I add extra parameters to the auth path? (besides the typical `username`, `password`, `grant_type`)?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

So, to answer my own question, correct me if I'm wrong but:

```
var remoteIpAddresss = context.Request.RemoteIpAddress;
```

is the **client's IP** Address (the user requesting the auth token), and

```
var localIpAddress = context.Request.LocalIpAddress;
```

is the **Web Api's IP** address (where the API is hosted).

Comment: I was wondering this too so I set up a project on a VM (with a different IP), sent a request to it from the host machine and you are indeed correct. `context.Request.RemoteIpAddress` showed the IP of the client requesting the token and `context.Request.LocalIpAddress` showed the IP where the API is hosted.